# not passing variable from controller to template yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $rows = Players::find()->all();


        return $this->render('index', [
            'rows' => $rows
        ]);

    }
```

and view

`<h1><?=$listPlayer -> name?></h1>`

Error = Undefined variable '$listPlayer'

I re-read all the documentation and all the guides on the Internet and it works for everyone. Except me

**UPD**
Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $rows = Players::find()->all();


        return $this->render('index', [
            'rows' => $rows
        ]);

    }
```

view

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $listPlayer): ?>
            <h1><?= $listPlayer->name ?></h1>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: The updated code looks fine. If you are still getting `Undefined variable $listPlayer` error then you are still trying to use `$listPlayer` variable somewhere before the foreach loop or you are editing wrong view file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `<h1><?=$listPlayer -> name?></h1>` - hit some spaces between opening/closing tags (if you pasted as it is).

Second: define `$listPlayer`. There isn't any variable $listPlayer in your action. You have only $rows. Rows, I asume - has a list of players, if you need a list (... `->all()`).